# MultiTenant architecture in ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: cloud, multi-tenant

Creating a web app for schools with data of 1000s students. All schools will login to same app through web browser.

For this I am using `MultiTenant architecture`. The problem is that we dont have expertise in cloud platform(tool is .Net). So, Can we use `Flexible Computing`/`MultiTenancy` in  `ASP.NET Web Forms` or `ASP.NET MVC` and deploy it in cloud?

I know ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC applications can be deployed on cloud. But

> Will it give the flavour of cloud application or Some performance will reduce?

I am searching all over for help for many days.

Thanks for your Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any doubt, Asp.net MVC is a Chosen design pattern for many SaaS developers and Software Vendors for its robustness, RESTful URLS, Stateless Nature, SoC, TDD etc [Refer the link to see the complete benefits Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms and its specially meant for distributed applications and there wont be any performance bottleneck but it is completely up-to you to architect and develop your the application well. If you architect wrongly you may end up unmanageable, not readable, un-enhanceable application.

Next to Choosing Technology, i would recommend you to concentrate more on the Architecture, Cross Cutting Components and Non functional requirements such as

1. Security Framework
2. Caching
3. Exception Handling/ Logging /Auditing
4. Horizontal Partitioning
5. Tenant Management
6. License Management
7. Metering
8. Configuration Management
9. System and Security Settings etc

Having developed many applications and interacting with many developers,the biggest advantage is its continuous community support and the technologies and tools that Microsoft introduce every year. Good Luck